# The if(isset($_POST['next'])) isn't working, I can't seem to get it to work in any function, and I can't figure out why for the life of me

Tags: php

I am really having a hard time figuring out why `if(isset($_POST['next']))` isn't working. How can I call something like that within a function?

```
function questions($result){
    $options = array('A','B','C','D','E');
    echo "Please click 'Next'";
    echo "<p class = 'button'><input type='submit' name='next' value='Next'/></p>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if(isset($_POST['next'])) {
            echo "<h4>".$row['question']."</h4>";
            foreach($options as $option){
                $text = $row[$option];
                if($text)
                    echo "<br/><input type = 'radio' name = 'ans' value = '$option'>".$text."<br/>";
            }
            echo "<p class = 'button'><input type='submit' id='submit' class = 'answer' name='submitAns' value='Submit' /></p>";
            if(isset($_POST['submitAns'])){
                $answer = $row['answer'];
                if($_POST('ans') == $answer) { 
                    echo "<h4>Correct!</h4>";
                } else {
                    echo "<h4>Incorrect. Correct answer is: ".$answer."</h4>";
                }
                echo "<p class = 'button'><input type='submit' id='next' name='next' class = 'answer' value='Next' /></p>";
            }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['next'])){
        echo "End of questions for this exam";
    }
}
```

Comment: "isn't working" as in... what exactly?

Comment: are you sure that $_POST["next"] is set? run a print_r($_POST).

Comment: `$_POST` is a [superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php), so it doesn't matter that you're using it inside a function. Could you try `var_dump($_POST);` and see what it outputs? Am I correct in guessing that by "isn't working" you mean that it isn't set when you think it should be? Could you paste the code for the form that you expect to set `$_POST['next']`?

Comment: While re-formatting your code I've noticed that you omitted spaces between several `echo` calls and the following string, notably the 4th line immediately before the while loop. Your code may well be silently failing due to these syntax errors. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script so you know that the errors are not being hidden.

Comment: You have two `if(isset($_POST['next']))` in your code. Is that what you want?

Comment: Also need to adjust lines like `if($_POST('ans') == $answer) {` to `if($_POST['ans'] == $answer) {`

Answer (score 0):

Checking to see if a variable exists (`isset`) and checking to see whether a variable actually contains something (`empty`) are two different things. Try this:

```
function questions($result){
    $options = array('A','B','C','D','E');
    echo "Please click 'Next'";
    echo "<p class = 'button'><input type='submit' name='next' value='Next'/></p>";

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        if($_POST && isset($_POST['next']) && !empty($_POST['next'])) {
// ....
}
```